# Align 2 linear layouts and image view inside Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an android app where I want to align 2 linear layouts in a row  with image view in between these 2 layouts.I am not able to use android studio layout editor to achieve this.

Code for the layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
            <TextView
            android:text="DEFG"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
             />
        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            tools:text="1250"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColorLink="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/profile_image">

            <TextView
                android:text="ABCD"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                tools:text="1250"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColorLink="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/face"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

2 linear layouts in a row with Image view at the center of a relative layout (With Green background)

[image]

Am I doing something wrong with the arrangement of layout? How to implement such scenario?

Comment: Seems you are new to the android development, sorry I will not post answer! I want you to play with xml layout and code, it would help you to learn it perfectly!

Comment: You should use weight in linear layout

Comment: @PareshMayani sir , What a comment :p

Comment: y are u specific about relative layout ?? in fact this can be achieved from linear layout more easily... If i would not have read @PareshMayani comment u wud have an answer by now :-D

Comment: I second with @PareshMayani. However, since you're stuck, I'll provide you some hints. You used `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and   `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` in one layout. Read more about this RelativeLayout's attributes here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html and try to figure out what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` (Horizontal) 
set width to `0dp` and weight to `1` thus they will have the same width. And use `gravity` to put things in the `center`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:text="DEFG"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                tools:text="1250"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColorLink="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:text="ABCD"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                tools:text="1250"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColorLink="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using weight to the LinearLayout you can achieve this.

Check this code, but before copy pasting learn the logic of weight in LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/rounded_corner" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="DEFG" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView8"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColorLink="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                tools:text="1250" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/face" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/rounded_corner" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="ABCD" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColorLink="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                tools:text="1250" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```